# IllegalStateException in a basic MyFirstApp

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I've created and ran the basic android MyFirstApp

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

using an AVD in eclipse and I get the following error:

`"java.lang.IllegalStateException:` Could not find a method sendMesaage(View) in the `activity`class `com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity` for onClick handler on `view` class `android.widget.Button"`

The method exists and the onClick element exists:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMesaage"/>
```

Method call:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMesaageActivity.class);
    EditText edit_message= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = edit_message.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Is "sendMesaage" not meant to be "sendMessage"? Also we need to see your code if that is not the issue.

Comment: maybe you spelled message wrong? Post your main activity code...

Comment: This is quite clearly a spelling mistake.  The error code says exactly what is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a spelling error...there could be a "sendMesaage()" method. Although, I'm pretty positive that it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GrahamSmith. It seems so trivial now. I wish XML threw syntax/compiling errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Button 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

Method call:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMesaageActivity.class);
EditText edit_message= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = edit_message.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: nice misspelling of something :)

Comment: It's a simple misspelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check for extra spaces. I faced similar problem. Instead of mentioning function name as 'myOnClick' in layout xml file, I mistyped it as 'myOnClick '.